strings with backslash are not equal
I have two strings that contain a backslash character that look the same when I print them but they are not equal. "/ ANN STAY SHARP CR/YX MET ENCH"
When I print all the characters as hex, I notice that one string contains two backslash character whereas the other only contains one.
:52:5c:5c:59:
:52:5c:59:
xrbg_prod['skuName_FR'].apply(lambda y:(':'.join(hex(ord(x))[2:] for x in y)))

If I try and replace the backslash, it is only done for one string, other other remains unchanged
xrbg_prod['skuName_FR'] = xrbg_prod['skuName_FR'].str.replace('\\', '/', regex=False)

Do you have an explanation why this is occurring?
Can you give me any suggestions for cleaning these strings so that they are considered equal?

Maybe this answer will help you.

"/ ANN STAY SHARP CR/YX MET ENCH" doesn't contain a backslash. Is this string the result of your code?

Thanks for pointing out my error @Matthias. That was the result of my applying the replace logic.

The issue is that how python handles escape sequences in strings. A single backslash \ is used to escape special characters, therefore when \\ is in a string, python interprets it as a single backslash.
You can use r to prevent python from interpreting escape sequences:
r'\\'

or replace \\ with \ alltogether like this:
.str.replace('\\\\', '/')

There four \ because two of them escape the special character.
